# How to terminate a regex match in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Given a string:

```
hello"this is a test"this is another test"etc
```

How can I write a regex that selects anything before `"` then move onwards to the next match? So at the end, I get following matches:

```
hello
this is a test
this is another test
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for something like `[^"]+`

repeat once or more, any character which is not a `"`

example:

```
String s = "hello\"this is a test\"this is another test\"etc";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^\"]+").matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()));
}
```

will produce:

```
hello
this is a test
this is another test
etc
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the quote character.

Comment: @Francisc: I escape it for java, not for the regex - otherwise won't it regard it as end of the string, and I'll get a syntax error?

Comment: I don't use Java but it probably depends on quote context, in anycase, in RegExp you don't need to escape quotes.

Comment: @Francisc: correct, but it is tagged as java, I allowed myself to give the actual pattern that will be passed - it will later be parsed to `[^"]+`, the breaking is done the java compiler - to "know" it is not the end of the string - there will be no trace of the `\` in the actual regex. I editted the answer anyway - the java breaking is clear from the code snapped attached later.

Answer (score 3):

Use the String method "split" with " as separator.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Edit:

```
String s = "hello\"this is a test\"this is another test\"etc";
String matches[] = s.split("\"");
for (String str : matches) System.out.println(str);
```

gives

```
hello
this is a test
this is another test
etc
```

Comment: This is not a regex that matches what he wants, it's a work-around

Comment: Correct, I never claimed it is wrong - but it is a work-around, and that is NOT what the OP asked for. Note that if the OP is not actually looking for the `String`s themselves, but for some metadata, creating many `String` objects [what `split()` does] might be unefficient.